# C# Trying to make another form open when a certain application is open

Tags: c#, forms, checkbox, boolean, system.diagnostics

**Here is my code below**

```
using System.Diagnostics;


     while (Process.GetProcessesByName("Your Program").Length == 0);
            {

                if (Checkbox.Checked)
                {
                    form2.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    form2.Visible = false;
                }
            }
```

My problem is when **"Your Program"** is not open and the checkbox is checked it does not check and causes the application to freeze. I want the program to be able to check/uncheck regardless but only open the second form when the program is running.

Another problem I had was when **"Your Program"** was closed the form would still show which caused more issues like trying to uncheck the checkbox but ultimately leading to more freezing of the program until I had to kill it.

Comment: The code appears to be an infinite loop if the process does not equal “Your Program.” … In addition… The “;” character at the end of the `while` loop line of code smells.

Comment: whats the solution then?

Comment: The while loop statement at its end has semicolon, making it endless loop. Repeated checking without gap will freeze your app.

Comment: Remove the semicolon. And either insert a Sleep in your loop or call it from a timer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution this seemed to work a lot better then the while loop

```
 Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("Your Program");
            
             
            if (!checkbox.Checked || (pname.Length == 0))
            {
                form2.Visible = false;


            }
            else
            {
               
                form2.Visible = true;
            }
```

Doing this removed the error I had which works wonders for my code. Hopefully this helps someone and thanks everyone for your help :)